# bootstrap navbar interactive + structure

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

this is my Fiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qu3X7/13/)

i have a lot of html files that look something like this:

```
<head>
…
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49714666/menuforJsFiddle2.js"></script>
…
<script>
//some script stuff 
//...
</script>

</body>
```

my bootsrap navbar is being fed from an external file.

So, in my Fiddle, when I click TopMenu->Hour->Submenu1 all 3 will be hightlighted.because of this code:

```
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parents('li').addClass("active");
});
```

And, because i have `href="#"` in this line `<li><a href="#">subMenu1</a></li>\`

But, in my Real example i want to put something like `href="pageName.html"` in this line `<li><a href="#">subMenu1</a></li>\` but this does not work.  what I mean by that is, all 3 (TopMenu->Hour->Submenu1) will not be highlighted. It is like it changes the `menuforJsFiddle2.js` to highlight what has been clicked. but then it just loads up `pageName.html` and forgets what has been clicked. this is my understanding.

I am trying to understand why and how i can get this to work? I model of tackling this might be completely wrong?

**NOTE**:What I am trying to achive is multilple *.html files that all have the same nav bar at the top, but when a link in the menu is selected it will show that page and the menu bar will show this link that was selected. basic structure is something like:

-htmlfiles

-->*.html

-menu

-->menu.js

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, do you mean something like what [this page](http://samsudar.com) does?

I have a single `html` file that defines my navbar. It is inserted into pages using [grunt-bake](https://github.com/MathiasPaumgarten/grunt-bake). Then at the top of each page I have a little bit of js that basically says "find the page that I'm on and highlight it".

For more detail take a look at [this file](https://github.com/MathiasPaumgarten/grunt-bake), which is almost exactly how I've set up the site. Here's the pertinent bit of script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // We're not using jquery because jquery isn't loaded yet.
  document.getElementById('navbar-first').setAttribute('class', 'active');
</script>
```